# ListBox Retaining Selection Data after Requery

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently working with a list box that deletes values containing the selected text from a table. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub DeleteEntry_Click()

Dim DeleteTbl As String
Dim Msg As String



If IsNull(Me.lstSolution) = True Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a Entry", vbOKOnly, "No Entry Selected"
Else
    DeleteTbl = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo, "Delete Entries?")
    Msg = "Are you sure you wish to delete all entrys containing: "
    Msg = Msg & Me.lstSolution
    DeleteTbl = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo, "Delete Entries?")
End If

If DeleteTbl = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].SolutionText = '" & Me.lstSolution & "'"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Else
     'Do Nothing
End If

    Me.lstSolution.Requery

End Sub
```

The problem i have  is that after the entry clears from the table, and i click the button again (without selecting anything) the previously selected value appears in the MsgBox still. I need to clear this value so that an error message box appears, saying that no entry has been selected

Comment: How is lstSolution bound?

Comment: btw I find using `DoCmd.RunSQL` to generally be bad practice. It means you need to use `DoCmd.SetWarnings` which are a real pain if you forget to turn them back on/something goes wrong and they don't get turned back on. Instead `CurrentDb.Execute` should be used I think. This has the added benefit of returning a `RecordsAffected` property which you can use to determine how many records were deleted.

Comment: If you don't want a list box row selected, doesn't `Me!lstSolution.Value = Null` do that for you?

Comment: Hello sorry for the late reply, been really busy lately. lstSolution isnt bound as far as im aware. The lstSolution gains its data from a query ran on a button press but all of thats working. Ill ammend the DoCmd statement and implement your solution. And @HansUp unfortunately, that doesnt clear the data. I dont know why its retaining it

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue by adding in a NotSelected variable as follows:

```
Private Sub DeleteEntry_Click()

Dim DeleteTbl As String
Dim Msg As String
Dim NotSelected As String

If IsNull(Me.lstSolution) = True Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a Entry", vbOKOnly, "No Entry Selected"
    NotSelected = True
Else
    Msg = "Are you sure you wish to delete all entrys containing: "
    Msg = Msg & Me.lstSolution
    DeleteTbl = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo, "Delete Entries?")
    NotSelected = False
End If

If NotSelected = True Then
    End
ElseIf DeleteTbl = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete * FROM [Solutions] WHERE [Solutions].SolutionText = '" & Me.lstSolution & "'"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End If

    Me.lstSolution.Requery


End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting this works as you set boolean values, `True`, and `False` to a declared string type, `NotSelected`. If anything boolean would match to Integer values not String.

Answer (score 0):

`ListBox.Requery` does not refresh the `ListBox.Value`, nor `Listbox.Column(index)`

You must call `lstSolution.SetFocus` after `lstSolution.Requery`. That propagates new values from current recordset to listbox columns.

I'm not sure but I think it is a bug in MS Access.